# How to setProperty() in bulk without refreshing the model?

Tags: odata, sapui5, refresh

I have a default OData Model V2 and I'm trying to update some properties all at once.

Every time the setProperty() method is used, the model refreshes itself, and calling so many methods is causing some performance issues.

How can I set the changes without refreshing the model every time I call the setProperty() method and refreshing the model in the end?

```
    onAccept: function (oEvent) {
        var oModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel();
        oModel.setProperty("/QuoteItemSet(guid'" + this._sTliKey + "')/acceptedRateClass", true);
        oModel.setProperty("/QuoteItemSet(guid'" + this._sTliKey + "')/workflowStatus", "02");
        oModel.setProperty("/QuoteItemSet(guid'" + this._sTliKey + "')/accepted", true);
        oModel.setProperty("/QuoteItemSet(guid'" + this._sTliKey + "')/approvedRate", this._nApprovedRateValue);
        oModel.setProperty("/QuoteItemSet(guid'" + this._sTliKey + "')/approvedRateOnEdit", this._nApprovedRateValue);

    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method [`setRefreshAfterChange()`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel/methods/setRefreshAfterChange) which defines whether all bindings are updated after a change operation. Don't forget to refresh the model once all changes are done with [`refresh()`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel/methods/refresh) to check all bindings for updated data.

```
oModel.setRefreshAfterChange(false);
[set properties...]
oModel.refresh();
```

Comment: seams that oModel.setRefreshAfterChange(false); isn`t working.
setProperty() refresh only the property and oModel.refresh(); refresh all the model.
the my model is very big and to refresh it all take more time